# Can't use a new formatted partition after formatting with gparted. Permissions I guess

Tags: partitioning, permissions, gparted

Xubuntu 14.04.

I had a non used partition, and as my /home has become full I have had to format that unused partition.

(My desire was to merge that partition with /home as it is listed next to /home, but as home is in use I can't do it, I can't unmount it. Help with this would be much desired too, even prefered, should I use a live-CD?).

So I have formatted with gparted that new partition as ext4 and put a name/label "home2". When I launch gparted it asks me about the computers password, so I run it with privileges.

This new partition is listed in gparted as /dev/sda3.

Then I open this new partition in the file manager (Thunar) but can't create folders or copy there. If I list its properties it says:

Owner: Root
Access: Read and Write

Group: Root
Access: Read only

Others: Read only.

Some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your partition has been formatted with a filesystem which is owned by user and group root. Change it to your user id:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/
chown -R AlexN:AlexN /mnt/
umount /dev/sda3
```

Comment: Hey bain, sorry for asking again, how would these commands change to make an external HDD identified in my computer by sdc, and formatted to ext4 in 1 only partition, to allow me create and delete from any of my linux computers, some of them with different username?

Comment: mount the external partition on /mnt/ then do `chmod -R a+rw /mnt/`

Comment: When I execute the command "sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt/" the computer replys with "mount: /dev/sdc already mounted or /mnt/ busy
", but if I execute the command with the HDD unmounted it says "mount: special device /dev/sdc does not exist
", what I am doing wrong. Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Try `umount /mnt` then `mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt`

Comment: Just `chmod 1777 [MOUNTPOINT]`, so it works for all users. The 1 is supposed to prevent other users from deleting your files.